# Cant use href with IconButtonProps

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to create a wrapper for the IconButton. I want to be able to pass for example the component or href prop, but i'm not able to do this when passing the IconButtonProps to it. How would i be able to achieve this?

```
function NavIconLink(props : IconButtonProps) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const { ...rest } = props;
    
    return (    
        <IconButton
            {...rest}
            href=""
            className={classes.buttonLink}
        >
            {props.children}
        </IconButton>
    )
}
```

Comment: What is the exception thrown from passing the href or other props?

Comment: I'm not really proficient at TypeScript yet, but `TS2769: No overload matches this call.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution

Set the generic for the component type on the `IconButtonProps` type to `'a'`.

```
function NavIconLink(props: IconButtonProps<'a'>) {
```

#### Explanation

I am able to replicate your error.  If I just set an `href` there's not any problem.  But if I set the `href` *and* pass down all of `...rest` then I get the `No overload matches this call.` error.

The error trace is long, but it's the section on `Overload 1 of 3` that we want to resolve.  That's where you'll see errors like

> Types of property 'onCopy' are incompatible.
>
> Type '`ClipboardEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement> | undefined`' is not assignable to type '`ClipboardEventHandler<HTMLAnchorElement> | undefined`'.

In plain terms, the error is essentially "you're setting an `href` prop as if the element is an `HTMLAnchorElement`, but the other props are for an `HTMLButtonElement`".

We need to make sure that all of the props are the correct types for an `HTMLAnchorElement`.

If you look at the source for the `IconButtonProps` type, you'll see that it has a generic type parameter `D` which specifies the element.

```
export type IconButtonProps<
  D extends React.ElementType = IconButtonTypeMap['defaultComponent'],
  P = {}
> = OverrideProps<IconButtonTypeMap<P, D>, D>;
```

You'll also see that the default value for `D` is `button` -- that's why you're getting `HTMLButtonElement` in your error messages.

```
export type IconButtonTypeMap<
  P = {},
  D extends React.ElementType = 'button'
> = ExtendButtonBaseTypeMap<{
  props: P & {
    ...
  };
  defaultComponent: D;
  ...
}>;
```

So when you use this type, you need to specify that your `...rest` props should be for an `a` component instead of a `button`.  Set the first generic on `IconButtonProps` to `'a'` and your errors will go away.

```
function NavIconLink({ children, ...rest } : IconButtonProps<'a'>) {
  return (
    <IconButton
      { ...rest } // props for a link
      href="" // also a prop for a link
    >
      {children}
    </IconButton>
  )
}
```

Comment: This solves the problem. Thanks for taking time to specify the solution in detail.

Comment: I have a follow up to this discussion. Say if I wanted to pass the href prop to the NavIconLink? This cannot currently be done with your solution. How would I go about this?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. By using this though, the extended button is now always expecting there to be an href, whereas the base IconButton can be a button or an anchor. Is there a way to extend it so it uses all of the original typings as-is? If I do a similar thing with <Button> using ButtonProps it doesn't have this issue.